# Exact GR Solution for accelerating massive body

Tags: general-relativity, acceleration, metric-tensor

Is there an exact solution in General Relativity for a spherical mass that is accelerating in one dimension?

Comment: Comment to the post (v1): Accelerating relative to what?

Comment: Relative to a distant inertial observer

Comment: Schwarzschild metric + a change of coordinates